# How Rails decides which named route helper to use for ActiveRecord instance?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, routes, overriding

does anyone know how it works, and above all how to override it?

I work on a Rails 5.0.0.1 project. For practical reasons we use namespaced routes like

```
namespace :survey do
  resources :questions
  resources :answers
end
```

We have `Question` and `Answer` models accordingly.

The [documentation](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#creating-paths-and-urls-from-objects) tells, that the helper `link_to` can be used with simply passing the ActiveRecord instance as second parameter, which would mean in my case  to simple write the following in the view (haml):

```
= link_to 'Show question', @question
```

This works fine if there is no namespace but goes for the named helper method `question_path` even if the route is namespaced - instead of `survey_question_path`. The point is that I would like to **decide from an ActiveRecord instance which named route helper to use**.

The interesting thing is that Rails knows that the Question instance will have a named route like *question*_path, I just cannot figure out how.

**What I have figured out this far:**

- the second parameter of `link_to` uses a helper method `url_for`, which then chooses the appropriate (or not) named route helper - but how?
- the ActiveRecord instances have the method `model_name`, which contains attributes like `route_key` (plural) and `singular_route_key` - I am not sure if this has anything to do with what I am looking for, or even if it has how to override it.

I thought there was a simple method to override in the model like `to_partial_path` for `render @question`, or `self.controller_path` in the case of controllers to render actions from another view directory, but I cannot find it.

Any help would be appreciated.

**EDIT**

After some more googling I stumbled upon the following paragraph in [APIdock](https://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/RoutingUrlFor/url_for) (*Relying on named routes*):

> Passing a record (like an `Active Record`) instead of a hash as the options parameter will trigger the named route for that record. The lookup will happen on the name of the class. So passing a Workshop object will attempt to use the `workshop_path` route. If you have a nested route, such as `admin_workshop_path` you’ll have to call that explicitly (**it’s impossible for `url_for` to guess that route**).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Rails uses your model's `model_name`, that's it, and you shouldn't override that method. If you want to turn a `Question` into a call to `survey_question_path`, then you need to define your own `question_path` which returns `survey_question_path`...

```
def question_path(question)
  survey_question_path(question)
end
```

... or just use the full method name yourself.

You can also use arrays of symbols/models, which get passed directly to `url_for`:

```
= link_to 'Show question', [:survey, @question]
```

Comment: Yeah, as for the helper, I thought of it, only didn't like the idea... (my bad :-)). On the other hand, your second suggestion, whith the array, seems to solve my problem, THX. (As for the `model_name`, I didn't intend to override it, only the route_key attributes, but I think you are right...)

Answer (score 1):

As for your questions:

> - the second parameter of link_to uses a helper method url_for, which
>     then chooses the appropriate (or not) named route helper - but how?

If you follow the #url_for method you mentioned around the source, we'll be thrown around, from **ActionView::RoutingUrlFor** to **ActionDispatch::Routing::PolymorphicRoutes**

(source: https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/870dde4710f1492c83233620f343ec414a07a950/actionview/lib/action_view/routing_url_for.rb#L115).

In the **ActionDispatch::Routing::PolymorphicRoutes#polymorphic_url** method, it makes use of an internal class and calls **HelperMethodBuilder.polymorphic_method**, passing all given options (including your model class as 'record_or_hash_or_array' (yeah, I know...)).

A few lines below, on this method's declaration, you'll get thrown around small methods a bit more and end up on a method like this:

```
def self.build(action, type)
  prefix = action ? "#{action}_" : ""
  suffix = type
  if action.to_s == "new"
    HelperMethodBuilder.singular prefix, suffix
  else
    HelperMethodBuilder.plural prefix, suffix
  end
end

def self.singular(prefix, suffix)
  new(->(name) { name.singular_route_key }, prefix, suffix)
end

def self.plural(prefix, suffix)
  new(->(name) { name.route_key }, prefix, suffix)
end
```

(source: https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/3f2b7d60a52ffb2ad2d4fcf889c06b631db1946b/actionpack/lib/action_dispatch/routing/polymorphic_routes.rb)

As you can see, it'll decide if it's the **#new** action or not, and call either **#singular** or **#plural**, which will, in turn, answer your second question:

> - the ActiveRecord instances have the method model_name, which contains attributes like route_key (plural) and singular_route_key - I am not sure if this has anything to do with what I am looking for, or even if it has how to override it.

These two methods get assigned, as we can see above, to a lambda that is the first parameter to this inner class's initializer, which will be stored as **@key_strategy**. Back in **ActionView#UrlFor", on the first link I showed you, you see this call:

```
else
  builder.handle_model_call(self, options)
```

Which will pass on to a few methods on the Builder's side:

```
def handle_model(record)
  args  = []

  model = record.to_model
  named_route = if model.persisted?
    args << model
    get_method_for_string model.model_name.singular_route_key
  else
    get_method_for_class model
  end

  [named_route, args]
end

def handle_model_call(target, model)
  method, args = handle_model model
  target.send(method, *args)
end

private

def get_method_for_class(klass)
  name = @key_strategy.call klass.model_name
  get_method_for_string name
end

def get_method_for_string(str)
  "#{prefix}#{str}_#{suffix}"
end
```

And, if I haven't missed anything, this last method returns your URL path.

Comment: Wow! Spectacular... I tried the same - that's how I got to the `@question.model_name.singular_route_key`, I guess -, only got lost in the jungle of methods (for example there are at least 5 `url_for` methods and I didn't know which one to investigate further...). I just wondered if there was a way to override `singular_route_key`, but I think I'll manage without it. Thanks, anyway :-)